# How to make a constantly changing Discord bot rich presence in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord.py

So, I'm making a Discord bot. It works fine and the commands work too. What I'm trying to do is make the status, aka rich presence, constantly changing. For example, `/h > 1 sec later > /he > 1 sec later > /hel > one sec later > /help` and then just keep repeating that. So, I thought I would put it in a `while True:` loop. But, that would obviously stop the rest of the bot from functioning. Then, I thought I would use threading, but that also doesn't work(or maybe I'm doing it wrong). Then, I put the forever loop in the on_ready() function, and the status works, but it pauses for 15 seconds after it goes through a few characters. Also, it stops the rest of the bot meaning commands wouldn't work either. I'm not really sure what else to do.

Code:

```
import os
import random
import discord
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import time
from threading import Thread

from website import main

load_dotenv()
TOKEN= os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')
GUILD = os.getenv('GUILD_NAME')
print(TOKEN)

client = discord.Client()

async def update_presence():
    while True:
        await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name='/h'))
        time.sleep(1)
        await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name='/he'))
        time.sleep(1)
        await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name='/hel'))
        time.sleep(1)
        await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name='/help'))
        time.sleep(1)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Game('/help'))
    print(f'{client.user} has connected to Discord!')

main()
t = Thread(target=update_presence)
t.start()
client.run(TOKEN)
```

Answer (score 1):

Mixing coroutines and `Threading` is a bad idea, also `time.sleep` is a blocking function, use `asyncio.sleep` instead:

```py
import asyncio

async def update_presence():
    while True:
        await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name='/h'))
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name='/he'))
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name='/hel'))
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name='/help'))
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
```

And then use `loop.create_task` to create a background task

```py
bot.loop.create_task(update_presence())
```

Another option would be to use the discord.py extension `tasks`

```py
from discord.ext import tasks


@tasks.loop(seconds=1)
async def update_presence():
    await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name='/h'))
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name='/he'))
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name='/hel'))
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name='/help'))


update_presence.start()
```

#### References:

- [`asyncio.sleep`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.sleep)
- [`loop.create_task`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.create_task)
- [`tasks.loop`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/tasks/index.html#discord.ext.tasks.loop)
- [`Loop.start`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/tasks/index.html#discord.ext.tasks.Loop.start)

Comment: Although the threading worked, your solution is obviously a lot better. The problem where the status stops changing for about 15 seconds is probably something that Discord implemented. It seems like Discord limits how often you can change your status, so that's something it doesn't seem like there's a workaround for.

Comment: @Luckstern you got a ratelimt for 5 Presence Updates per 60 Seconds and this per session. But you have to be careful not getting too close to this as it is dynamic

Comment: I realized that there was probably a limit. So, I just removed the code and made a static status.